# Short story in which a boy/teenager's space-faring uncle gives him an egg-shaped object that hatches into a flying creature with unique abilities

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

A young boy/teenager's space-faring uncle gives him an egg-shaped object which unexpectedly hatches into a flying creature with unique abilities.

I read this in a in 1950-60's SyFy pulp magazine.

Comment: So the *egg-shaped object* was in fact an egg?

Comment: Can you be more specific about any of the abilities that the creature had?

Comment: @Valorum. Duck typing at its finest